# sqlalchemy label

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, label

I'm confused how the .label(...) function works in SqlAlchemy. I've got a query something like this:

```
data = session.query(Coupon, func.isnull(Order.coupon_code).label("redeemed")) \
  .outerjoin((Order, Order.coupon_code == Coupon.coupon_code)) \
  .all()
```

When this query runs, I see the order.coupon_code as redeemed in the resulting query, but in a return row of the data I get two things, the coupon structure, and a '0' or '1'). Looks something like this:

```
[(Coupon:
  coupon_id = 1234
  etc 
  , 0),
 ... ]
```

What I would like is if the '0' or '1' were named 'redeemed' with a value of '0' or '1'. Something like this:

```
[(Coupon:
  coupon_id = 1234
  etc 
  , 
  redeemed = 0),
 ... ]
```

I guess I don't understand what label is doing for me, if anything. If someone has some hints or direction about how I might get the data the way I'm thinking, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

You can map computed values to class attributes using [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#mapper-sql-expressions), which seems to be closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, column_property looks very useful, though I'm not sure it is so in this case. I could just get everything from both objects in the query like this session.query(Coupon, Order), but I only really need to get the one field, Order.coupon_code, from Order.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/test', echo=True)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Date, Column, Integer


Base = declarative_base()



class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    day = Column(Date, unique=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)
    session = Session()

    a = session.query(User.day.label('test')).all()

    print "New Label :", a[0].test
    print "DIR :", dir(a[0])
```

When you run the script and last statement is `dir` of the first row. And there you will get the `test` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the example, which is very useful. I will try that out in my context and see if it gives me what I'm after.